# PHP: sscanf extract values from string within double quotes

Tags: php, scanf

I'm trying to parse the 2 values contained within double quotes from a session string. The other string variables are not constant and therefore can not use any additional characters as markers.  I only need the quoted values. My following sscanf function is incomplete.

```
$string = 'a:1:{s:14:"174.29.144.241";s:8:"20110508";}';

sscanf($string,'%[^"]', $login_ip, $login_date);

echo $login_ip;
echo $login_date;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not use regx it is more flexible

Answer (score 2):

That data is just PHP serialized text from `serialize()`

In which case you can get at the data you need with:

```
$sessionData = unserialize('a:1:{s:14:"174.29.144.241";s:8:"20110508";}');
list($ip, $date) = each($sessionData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'a:1:{s:14:"174.29.144.241";s:8:"20110508";}';

preg_matches("/(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)/",$string,$matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

This should return your ip address. consult [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: you can extend the regex to make it match your date also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do that.

```
$string = 'a:1:{s:14:"174.29.144.241";s:8:"20110508";}';
$pattern = '/"(?P<ip>[^"]*)"[^"]*"(?P<date>[^"]*)"/';
preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches );
echo $matches['ip'].' '.$matches['date'];
```

First quoted value will go to ip, second to date.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting hack would be to use explode using " as the separator like this:

```
<?php
$res = explode('"','a:1:{s:14:"174.29.144.241";s:8:"20110508";}');
print_r($res);
?>
```

Any value in double quotes would be returned in an odd index i.e $res[1], $res[3]